# When I call gorm Automigrate code I am getting "ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table DC (SQLSTATE 42830)"

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have the following structs

```
type datacenter struct {
    Name          string    `gorm:"unique" json:"name"`
    Datacenter_Id uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;primaryKey" json:"datacenter_id"`
    Cluster_List []Cluster  `gorm:"foreignKey:Datacenter_Id" json:"clusters"`
    CreatedAt    time.Time
    UpdatedAt    time.Time
    DeletedAt    gorm.DeletedAt `gorm:"index"`
}
```

```
type Cluster struct {
    Cluster_Id      uuid.UUID      `gorm:"type:uuid;primary_key;unique" json:"id"`
    Num             int            `gorm:"unique" json:"num"`
    Datacenter_Id   uuid.UUID      `json:"Datacenter_id"`                        
    Servers_List    []Server       `gorm:"foreignKey:Cluster_Id" json:"servers"`
    CreatedAt       time.Time      `json:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt       time.Time      `json:"updatedAt"`
    DeletedAt       gorm.DeletedAt `gorm:"index"`
}
```

```
type Server struct {
    Scale_unit    int       `gorm:"unique" json:"scale_unit"`
    Server_Id     uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;primaryKey" json:"server_id"`
    IP_Address    string    `json:"ip_address"`
    Cluster_Id    uuid.UUID `json:"cluster_id"`
    CreatedAt     time.Time
    UpdatedAt     time.Time
    DeletedAt     gorm.DeletedAt `gorm:"index"`
}
```

I am calling the gorm automigrate code to create table in postgresql

```
if err := My_DB.AutoMigrate(&models.Datacenter{}); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error auto-migrating: %v", err)
    }

    if err := My_DB.AutoMigrate(&models.Cluster{}); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error auto-migrating: %v", err)
    }

    if err := My_DB.AutoMigrate(&models.Server{}); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error auto-migrating: %v", err)
    }
```

But I keep getting the below error

```
2023/12/21 22:50:49 /app/database/db.go:116 ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "datacenters" (SQLSTATE 42830)
[13.584ms] [rows:0] CREATE TABLE "clusters" ("cluster_id" uuid UNIQUE,"num" bigint UNIQUE,"datacenter_id" uuid,"created_at" timestamptz,"updated_at" timestamptz,"deleted_at" timestamptz,PRIMARY KEY ("cluster_id"),CONSTRAINT "fk_datacenters_clusters_list" FOREIGN KEY ("datacenter_id") REFERENCES "datacenters"("datacenter_id"))
2023/12/21 22:50:49 Error auto-migrating: ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "datacenters" (SQLSTATE 42830)
```

My idea is to have a datacenter struct that has bunch of clusters and each clusters contains numerous servers. I trying to establish this relation using foreign key and I keep hitting with above error, I had "unique" constraint to datacenter_id but still it was giving me same error. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It's called has many relation and in Gorm there is a [documentation](https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html)

Also I recommend You to follow [naming conventions](https://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html) if You want Gorm to work as expected.

And based on that docs models must be designed following way:

```
type Datacenter struct {
    gorm.Model

    ID              uuid.UUID      `gorm:"type:uuid;primaryKey" json:"id"`
    Name            string         `gorm:"unique" json:"name"`
    Clusters        []Cluster      `gorm:"foreignKey:DatacenterID" json:"clusters"`
    CreatedAt       time.Time      `gorm:"autoCreateTime:true" json:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt       time.Time      `gorm:"autoUpdateTime:true" json:"updatedAt"` 
    DeletedAt       gorm.DeletedAt `gorm:"index"`
}

type Cluster struct {
    gorm.Model

    ID              uuid.UUID      `gorm:"type:uuid;primaryKey" json:"id"`
    Num             int            `gorm:"unique" json:"num"`
    DatacenterID    uuid.UUID      `json:"datacenterId"`                        
    Servers         []Server       `gorm:"foreignKey:ClusterID" json:"servers"`
    CreatedAt       time.Time      `gorm:"autoCreateTime:true" json:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt       time.Time      `gorm:"autoUpdateTime:true" json:"updatedAt"` 
    DeletedAt       gorm.DeletedAt `gorm:"index"`
}

type Server struct {
    gorm.Model

    ID              uuid.UUID      `gorm:"type:uuid;primaryKey" json:"id"`
    ScaleUnit       int            `gorm:"unique" json:"scaleUnit"`
    IPAddress       string         `json:"ipAddress"`
    ClusterID       uuid.UUID      `json:"clusterId"`
    CreatedAt       time.Time      `gorm:"autoCreateTime:true" json:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt       time.Time      `gorm:"autoUpdateTime:true" json:"updatedAt"` 
    DeletedAt       gorm.DeletedAt `gorm:"index"`
}
```

Comment: You are saying this should be created in the reverse manner when calling the automigrate methids?

Comment: @Lethargic_Sun writing in reverse manner is not solution.